# Step ‘Run Tests on AWS Device Farm’ aborted due to exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not generate secret

Tags: testing, mobile, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, aws-device-farm

I am trying to integrate the Jenkins with AWS device Farm to automate the Mobile device testing.
    So, i had created an IAM user and attached the devicefarm policy to teh user.
    Generated AWS Access Key ID & AWS Secret Key ID and provied in the jenkins manage configurations.

```
But the Post-build Actions to Run Tests on AWS Device Farm leads to below exception. Could anyone be able to help me?
```

**Exception stackstrace is as below:**

```
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using Project 'BMS_OPDVO'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using DevicePool 'LG Nexus5'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Using App '**/target/resources/org.wordpress.android.5.0.apk'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Archiving artifact 'org.wordpress.android.5.0.apk'
[AWSDeviceFarm] Uploading org.wordpress.android.5.0.apk to S3
ERROR: Step ‘Run Tests on AWS Device Farm’ aborted due to exception: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not generate secret
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(ECDHCrypt.java:103)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1067)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.awsdevicefarm.AWSDeviceFarm.upload(AWSDeviceFarm.java:359)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.awsdevicefarm.AWSDeviceFarm.upload(AWSDeviceFarm.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.awsdevicefarm.AWSDeviceFarm.upload(AWSDeviceFarm.java:317)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.awsdevicefarm.AWSDeviceFarm.uploadApp(AWSDeviceFarm.java:211)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.awsdevicefarm.AWSDeviceFarmRecorder.perform(AWSDeviceFarmRecorder.java:287)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: ECDH key agreement requires ECPublicKey for doPhase
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.KeyAgreementSpi.engineDoPhase(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.doPhase(KeyAgreement.java:567)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(ECDHCrypt.java:100)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you format your question properly?

Comment: @Jannik, Thanks. Frankly this is my frist question in SO. I tried using the ctrl+k. will try more formatting from my next post.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is basically because of the ssl handshaking between the jenkins and s3 server is not happening.

I had installed **skip certificate check plugin** and restarted the jenkins server which ignored the ssl handshaking error and proceeded with the operation.